# dictionary that return website status code as key and website as value - py

Tags: python

Hey guys I need a bit of guidance with this problem ( .py noobie)

So I have a list of websites that have different status codes:

```
url_list=["http://www.ehow.com/foo-barhow_2323550_clean-coffee-maker-vinegar.html",
          "http://www.google.com",
          "http://livestrong.com/register/confirmation/",
          "http://www.facebook.com",
          "http://www.youtube.com"]
```

What i'm trying to return is a dictionary that returns the website's status code as key and the associated websites as values. Something like that:

```
result= {"200": ["http://www.google.com",
                 "http://www.facebook.com",
                 "http://www.youtube.com"], 
         "301": ["http://livestrong.com/register/confirmation/"],
         "404": ["http://www.ehow.com/foo-barhow_2323550_clean-coffee-maker-vinegar.html"]}
```

What I have till now:

Function that gets the status code:

```
def code_number(url):
    try:
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        code = u.code
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        code = e.code
    return code
```

And a function should return the dictionary but is not working - the part where i got stuck. Basically I dont know how to make it insert in the same status code more than 1 url

```
result={}
def get_code(list_of_urls):
    for n in list_of_urls:
        code = code_number(n)
        if n in result:
            result[code] = n
        else:
            result[code] = n
    return result
```

Any ideas please?! Thank you

Comment: Just a note, if you have a large list of URLs from the same domain (eg: [foo.bar/1, foo.bar/2, etc..]) I suggest you put a short timeout between requests so your program does not get mistaken for a DDOS attack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict` makes this a breeze:

```
import collections

def get_code(list_of_urls):
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for n in list_of_urls:
        code = code_number(n)
        result[code].append(n)
    return result
```

Not sure why you had `result` as a global, since it's returned as the function's result anyway (avoid globals except when really indispensable... locals are not only a structurally better approach, but also faster to access).

Anyway, the `collections.defaultdict` instance `result` will automatically call the `list` argument, and thus make an empty list, to initialize any entry `result[n]` that wasn't yet there at the time of indexing; so you can just append to the entry without needing to check whether it was previously there or not.  **That** is the super-convenient idea!

If for some reason you want a plain `dict` as a result (though I can't think of any sound reason for needing that), just `return dict(result)` to convert the `defaultdict` into a plain `dict`.

Comment: The most Pythonic answer.

Comment: Thank Alex, your code works great however it doesn't work the way I want it. Instead of grouping the urls by status code, what is does is to display the status code for each URL:  {'http://www.google.com': [200], 'http://livestrong.com/regidadasdsa': [404], 'http://www.ehow.com/foo-barhow_2323550_clean-coffee-maker-vinegar.html': [404], 'http://www.facebook.com': [200]})

Comment: @RaduAndrei, just edited the answer to show how to get exactly what you ask -- just swapped `n` and `code` in the `append`.

Comment: Sweet!! this definitely works. I didnt work with collections till now , had no idea about them but ill look over it now. Now I'm curious for a solution with the result as a global ? How would that look? Sorry if i'm pushing it , im just trying to learn and see more aspects of the problem

Comment: @RaduAndrei, you can move the `result =` line just before the `def` for the function, and this will make it global, make your code more fragile, and slow it down a bit.  Why anyone would **want** to do that escapes me -- maybe because "it feels so good when you stop"?-)

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize every key of the dict with a list, to which you will append any websites that return the same status code. Example:

```
result={}
def get_code(list_of_urls):
    for n in list_of_urls:
        code = code_number(n)
        if code in result:
            result[code].append(n)
        else:
            result[code] = [n]
    return result
```

I also think that the condition should be `if code in result`, since your keys are the return codes.

Comment: I'm running in the same issue, if there are 2 url with the same status code it prints only 1 ...